# Get database last N data points from each node (Cloudant/couchdb)

Tags: database, couchdb, cloudant

TL;DR: MapReduce or POST request?

What is the correct(=most efficient) way to fetch the latest n data points of multiple sensors, from Cloudant or equivalent database?

Sensor data is stored in individual documents like this:

```
{
  "_id": "2d26dbd8e655ae02bdab611afc92b6cf",
  "_rev": "1-a64448521f05935b915e4bee12328e84",
  "date": "2017-06-20T15:59:50.509Z",
  "name": "Sensor01",
  "temperature": 24.5,
  "humidity": 45.3,
  "rssi": -33
}
```

I want the fetch the latest 10 documents from sensor01-sensor99 so I can feed it to UI.

I have discovered few options:

**1. Use map reduce function**

Reduce each sensor data to array under sensor01, sensor02, etc...

E.g.
Map:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.name && doc.temperature) emit(doc.name, doc.temperature);
}
```

Reduce:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  var temp_arr=[];

  for (i=0;i<values.length;i++)
  {
    temp_arr.push(values);
  }
  return temp_arr;
}
```

I couldn't get this to work, but I think the method should be viable.

**2. Multi-document fetching**

> ```
> {
> "queries":[
> {sensor01},{sensor02},{sensor03} etc....
> ]};
> ```

Where each {sensor0x} is filtered using

```
{"startkey": [sensors[i],{}],"endkey": [sensors[i]],"limit": 5}
```

This way I can order documents using ?descending=true
I implemented it and it works. I have my doubts should I use this if I have 1000 sensors with 10000 data points each.
And for hundreds of sensors I need to send a very large POST request.

3. Something better?

Is my architecture even correct?
Storing sensor data individual documents, and then fill the UI by fetching all data through REST API.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your method of storing one reading per document, but there's no truly efficient way of getting "the last n data points" for a number of sensors.

We could create a MapReduce function:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.name && doc.temperature && doc.date) {
    emit([doc.name, doc.date], doc.temperature);
  }
}
```

This creates an indexed ordered on `name` and date.

We can access the most recent readings for a single sensor by querying the view:

```
/_design/mydesigndoc/_view/myview?startkey=["Sensor01","2020-01-01"]&descending=true&limit=10
```

This fetches readings for "Sensor01" in newest-first order:

- startkey & endkey are reveresed when doing descending=true
- descending= true means in reverese order
- limit - the number of readings required (or n in your parlance)

This is a very efficient use of Cloudant/CouchDB but it only returns the last n readings for single sensor. To retrieve other sensors' data, additional API calls would be required.

Creating an index like this:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.name && doc.temperature && doc.date) {
    emit(doc.date, doc.temperature);
  }
}
```

orders each reading by date. You can then retrieve the newest n readings with:

```
/_design/mydesigndoc/_view/myview?startkey="2020-01-01"&descending=true&limit=200
```

If all of your sensors are saving data at the same rate, then simply using a larger limit should get your the latest readings of all sensors.

This too is an efficient use of CouchDB/Cloudant.

You may also want to look at the built-in reducers (_count, _sum and _stats) to get the database to aggregate readings for you. They are a great way to create year/month/day groupings of IoT data.

In general, I would recommend *not* using custom reducers they are many times more inefficient than the built-in reducers which are written in Erlang.

Comment: I was able to use this method, but is it efficient, when I have to query individually 100 times? Or should I still use the very large POST request instead? I'd think that many queries in a row will also reach the 5 Queries/sec limit.
I'm just wondering is 100x API calls worse than POST request with 100 items, or should I just download the ENTIRE database and parse it manually... Thank you very much!
(also, some of the sensors might be offline for weeks, but I still need to get their latest data, so using master sort doesn't apply)

Comment: fewer API calls is generally a better. And yes, if you're on a rate-limited plan, you'd have to be careful not to exceed your allocation :)